# print fitting results to terminal in Gnuplot

Tags: printing, gnuplot

I want to perform a really simple task, which I just can't achieve myself. I want to use fitting parameters, e.g. a1, a2, a3, do some basis mathematics with it and print the result to my terminal as a simple output (like cout "Hello World").

I want something like this in Gnuplot:

```
print 'the result C = a0+a1+a2'
```

And an output like (e.g. if all parameters are equal to 1)

```
the result C = 3
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sprintf` to format a string based on some variables:

```
print sprintf('the result is C = %.2f', a0 + a1 + a2)
```

Comment: That did the job. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you also need errors, do this:

```
set fit errorvariables
fit ...
print sprintf(' a0 has been determined to %d  +/- %d', a0, a0_err)
```

Due to the `set fit` command, there will be an additional variable `*_err"` for each variable after the fit.